# Scala. Compiler fails when curried function parameter instantiated in different ways

Tags: scala, dsl, currying

I'm new to Scala, trying to master DSL creation tricks. Can't figure out why compiler behaves differently in the following 2 scenarios when **a)** I instantiate class B directly and **b)** when I do the same by wrapper method or value.

```
object Example {
  def createB: B = new B
  class B

  def createA: A = new A
  class A {
    def aMethod(b: B)(p: String => Unit): Unit = {}
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // this compiles fine
    createA aMethod new B { s: String =>
    }

    // this does not compile, as compiler tries to apply function (String => Unit) to class B
    createA aMethod createB { s: String =>
    }

    // this does not compile either
    val bb = new B
    createA aMethod bb { s: String =>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're new to scala I would not jump into writing DSLs for anything other than toy throwaway tasks

Comment: That's what I'm doing basically, working on throwaway tasks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first example:

```
createA aMethod new B { s: String => }
```

may compile, but it isn't doing what you expect.  You are actually constructing an instance of B that has the self type of String (refer to [this](http://marcus-christie.blogspot.com/2014/03/scala-understanding-self-type.html) and [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html) for more information).  The return type of that statement then is a Function that takes a Function of String to Unit and returns Unit.  More simply, you have not provided a value for parameter p to your function, aMethod.

Your issue in all three examples is just a syntactic one.  The compiler is really confused and doesn't know where you are giving it a function and where you are extending classes.  When that is the case I like to explicitly add the periods and parens for function calls.  All three of these should now compile and do what you want:

```
createA.aMethod(new B) { s: String =>
}

createA.aMethod(createB){ s: String =>
}

val bb = new B
createA.aMethod(bb){ s: String =>
}
```

Edit:
An alternative by directly calling apply on the curried function, this may be your best bet:

```
class A {
  def aMethod(b: B)(p: String => Unit): Unit = {}
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  createA aMethod new B apply { s: String =>
  }

  createA aMethod createB apply { s: String =>
  }

  val bb = new B
  createA aMethod bb apply { s: String =>
  }
}
```

If you hate using 'apply' you could also construct an object with whatever name you want:

```
class A {
  def aMethod(b: B) = new {
    def myCoolName(p: String => Unit): Unit = {}
  }
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  createA aMethod new B myCoolName { s: String =>
  }

  createA aMethod createB myCoolName { s: String =>
  }

  val bb = new B
  createA aMethod bb myCoolName { s: String =>
  }
}
```

Another alternative with aMethod not curried:

```
class A {
  def aMethodNotCurried(b: B, p: String => Unit): Unit = {}
}

def mainNotCurried(args: Array[String]) {
  createA aMethodNotCurried (new B, { s: String =>
  })

  createA aMethodNotCurried (createB, { s: String =>
  })

  val bb = new B
  createA aMethodNotCurried (bb, { s: String =>
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation Karl, I get it now. 

But I'm still wondering if there is a way to call aMethod(..)(..) with DLSish style, to make compiler figure out that I'm trying to pass function to aMethod rather than to B class

Comment: Invoking a curried method like aMethod(..)(..) is just syntactic sugar for aMethod(..) apply(..).  You can omit the dot and parens for functions with arity 0 and 1 but nothing more from my knowledge (http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html).  I'll edit my answer to show examples of using apply and no currying, but I don't believe what you specifically want can be done.  It seems too ambiguous for the compiler.